# Is it possible to install scip on centos 6.5

Tags: centos, scip

Is there anyone knows if I can install scip in centos 6.5?
I take a try but it doesn't work. I don't know i have a mistake in installation process or it can't work on centos!
I install scip on ubuntu correctly.
thanks in advance,
Elnaz

Comment: Please, could you provide more information about the things that went wrong?

Comment: thank you for your reply.I give this error when i try to install scip on centos:
compiling obj/static/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o
bash: gcc: command not found
make[1]: *** [obj/static/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o] Error 127
make: *** [libscip] Error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build SCIP on CentOS 6.5.

Comment: thank you for your reply.but I take this error when i try to install scip on centos, may you help me about this?
: compiling obj/static/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o bash: gcc: command not found make[1]: *** [obj/static/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o] Error 127 make: *** [libscip] Error 2 –

Comment: Install gcc (yum install gcc or similar).